# How do compilers implement dataflow analysis for arrays and pointers due to aliasing related to array indices and pointer addresses

Tags: compiler-construction, compiler-optimization, dataflow, intermediate-language, compiler-specific

I have looked online through google search for the above question but didn't find a easy to understand high-level idea of the approach for it. I have read through the Engineering-a-Compiler Textbook by Cooper/Torczon ([https://www.amazon.com/Engineering-Compiler-Keith-Cooper/dp/012088478X](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/012088478X)) but that doesn't talk about dataflow analysis for Arrays. I understand dataflow analysis for Scalars and advanced IRs like SSA.

Any easy to grasp explanations on how it's done for arrays/pointers?

Comment: Alias analysis is very dependent on language semantics. That may be why there aren't many good general discussions. You might start with the documentation on [how LVVM supports alias analysis](https://llvm.org/docs/AliasAnalysis.html) and then look at some of its real uses.

Comment: what about array dataflow analysis (slightly different than alias analysis) specifically for C or C-like language?

Comment: Too broad. This is a whole semester subject on its own. Have a look at the Green Dragon book to start.

Comment: @user207421 I did already, but it doesn't fully handle it. The question was asking for a simple high-level ideas instead of complete details.